# Controls have locked min. width or max size

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a form with a tableLayoutPanel. It has 1 column and 2 rows with 2 controls. A label and a listView. In design mode I cant set the label height larger than 17. And the listView I can manualy enlarge but not shrink. The controls dimensions remain larger that the form itself. So either the controls are cliped or I end up with the forms scrollbars. So why the controls autosize larger than the form? And when I run the app they dont shrink to minSize either.

```
// 
// labelTitle
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.labelTitle, "labelTitle");
this.labelTitle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
this.labelTitle.Name = "labelTitle";
// 
// tableLayoutPanel
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel, "tableLayoutPanel");
this.tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(this.labelTitle, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(this.aListView, 0, 1);
this.tableLayoutPanel.GrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize;
this.tableLayoutPanel.Name = "tableLayoutPanel";
// 
// aListView
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.aListView, "aListView");
this.aListView.AllowDrop = true;
this.aListView.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Desktop;
this.aListView.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
this.aListView.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
this.aListView.LargeImageList = this.coverImageList;
this.aListView.MultiSelect = false;
this.aListView.Name = "aListView";
this.aListView.ShowGroups = false;
this.aListView.ShowItemToolTips = true;
this.aListView.TileSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
this.aListView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.aListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Tile;
// 
// form
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Desktop;
this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel);
this.Name = "Form";
this.albumsContextMenu.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tableLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Instead of docking the controls I anchored them. Now I can change their size in design mode if I start with the top control first.

Comment: Set the Form to AutoSize seems to be a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 3):

A `Label` has `AutoSize = true` by default, which resizes the control based on content and ignores your manual settings.

Before seeing the effect of you changing the size, you must disable the `AutoSize` property.

```
label1.AutoSize = false;
label1.Height = 50;
```

*(Note that you can set the Height first, but you won't see the effect until you disable AutoSize.)*

---

For the second question, you'll have to elaborate on what you mean by *"the listView only grows in size"*.

Comment: But why is the vertical size of my ListView Width locked at aprox. 600? It has MinSize.Width 400. I have now set the MinSize of the Form large enough so the ListView cant be bigger that the the Form.